# Variable Not Resetting on Group. Instead taking max values for entire Group

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating a `Jaspersoft` `iReport` for a logistics company.

My report structure is like this.

```
...
Sku Group 
Pallet Group 
Details 
Pallet Group Footer 
Sku Group Footer 
...
```

So the final report looks like this:

`^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ qty ^^^^^ weight`

`Item Code A         127      600`

`^^ Pallet A1         80       450`

`^^ Pallet A2         80       450`

`Item Code B         200      530`

`etc. etc.`

## Issue

The true value for `qty` of `Pallet A1` should be 47 and its `weight` should be 150.

However, my variable has instead put in the `qty` and `weight` information fro `Pallet A2` for both of my pallets holding `Item A`

The variable is setup as follows

```
<variable name="PalletQty" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Pallet" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{QtyReceived}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="PalletWeight" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Pallet" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{WeightReceived}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
```

Can someone help me find the reason it is not evaluating properly?

I am using a variable to `Sum` for the Pallet Qty because some of the Pallets contain cases on them, and I need to `Sum` the individual case quantities in order to `output` the pallet `qty`.